# Why does psycopg2 "DELETE" result in a programming error?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

following the documentation for [SQL String composition](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql), I want to execute a DELETE statement in my postgresql database:

```
db_cursor.execute(sql.SQL("DELETE FROM {}".format(sql.Identifier(table_name))))
```

This results in the error:

```
File "try_pandas.py", line 189, in _store_in_table
db_cursor.execute(sql.SQL("DELETE FROM {}".format(sql.Identifier(table_name))))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: DELETE FROM Identifier('fixture_identification')
```

Another, similar execute is working fine:

```
db_cursor.copy_expert(sql.SQL("COPY {} FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER").format(sql.Identifier(table_name)), table_file)
```

I really don't see the difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is here:

```
sql.SQL("DELETE FROM {}".format())
```

It should be

```
sql.SQL("DELETE FROM {}").format() # Notice the brackets.
```

Comment: I once was blind, but now I see... Thanks :)